# Why does this program terminate on my system but not on playground?

Tags: concurrency, go, undefined-behavior

Consider this program:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "runtime"

func main() {

    x := 0

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        x = 1
    }()

    for x == 0 {
        runtime.Gosched()
    }

    fmt.Println("it works!")
}
```

Why does it terminate locally but not on [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/X2QNaNUzYD)? Does the termination of my program rely on undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't offer much guarantees.  It's relying almost entirely on implementation details around undefined behavior.

In most multi-threaded systems, there's no guarantee that a change in one thread with no barrier will be seen in another.  You've got a goroutine which could be running on another processor altogether writing a value to a variable nobody's ever guaranteed to read.

The `for x == 0 {` could quite easily be rewritten to `for {` since there's never a guarantee any changes to that variable might be visible.

The race detector will also probably report this issue.  You should really not expect this to work.  If you want a `sync.WaitGroup` you should just use one as it properly coordinates across threads.

Comment: This might be true in C, but in Go there are things that might modify the value of x; one of them is the assignment in the Go routine. A compiler that would optimize away the check is faulty.

Comment: Apparently, busy waiting is indeed [undefined behavior](http://golang.org/ref/mem) in Go. Still, my previous comment holds.

Comment: @FUZxxl: this isn't a case of the check being optimised away.  See my answer for why the code is guaranteed not to work on playground.

Comment: No, a compiler optimizing a way a check with no barrier isn't faulty, the code is.  If you write correct code and the compiler makes something unexpected happen, you can blame the compiler.  Go's built-in race detector very clearly and easily tells you that your code is wrong: http://pastebin.com/Hcin6vrC

Comment: Right.  But you could rewrite the program without the memory race (e.g. add a mutex, use atomic operations) and still have it fail on the playground due to the special `time.Sleep` implementation.

Comment: That's a good example of exploiting the implementation detail there, James.  FTR, I'm not saying that optimization is actually performed, just that it's valid.  I have actually seen this happen in real code and it's a fine optimization.

Answer (score 5):

The Go playground uses a special implementation of `time.Sleep` designed to prevent individual programs from monopolising the back end resources of the website.

As described in [this article about the how the playground is implemented](http://blog.golang.org/playgroun), goroutines that call time.Sleep() are put to sleep.  The playground back end waits until all other goroutines are blocked (what would otherwise be a deadlock), and then wakes the goroutine with the shortest time out.

In your program, you have two goroutines: the main one, and one that calls `time.Sleep`.  Since the main goroutine never blocks, the `time.Sleep` call will never return.  The program continues until it exceeds the CPU time allocated to it and is then terminated.

Comment: +1 for a nice explanation of why the program fails on the playground. I have posted an answer that tries to explain why the program is not guaranteed to work correctly in the general case (based on the rules of the Go Memory Model.

Answer (score 4):

The Go Memory Model does not guarantee that the value written to x in the goroutine will ever be observed by the main program. A similarly erroneous program is given as an example in the section on [go routine destruction](http://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_5). The Go Memory Model also specifically calls out busy waiting without synchronization as an incorrect idiom in [this section](http://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_9).

You need to do some kind of synchronization in the goroutine in order to guarantee that x=1 *happens before* one of the iterations of the for loop in main.

Here is a version of the program that is guaranteed to work as intended.

http://play.golang.org/p/s3t5_-Q73W

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan bool)
    x := 0

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        x = 1
        close(c) // 1
    }()

    for x == 0 {
        <-c // 2
    }

    fmt.Println("it works!")
}
```

The Go Memory Model guarantees that the line marked with // 1 *happens before* the line marked with // 2. As a result, the for loop is guaranteed to terminate before its second iteration.