# Why is this code Undefined Behavior?

Tags: go

```
  var x int
  done := false
  go func() { x = f(...); done = true }
  while done == false { }
```

This is a Go code piece. My fiend told me this is UB code. Why?

Comment: There is no `while` in Go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in "[Why does this program terminate on my system but not on playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589711/6309)"

> The Go Memory Model does not guarantee that the value written to x in the goroutine will ever be observed by the `main` program.
>   A similarly erroneous program is given as an example in the section on [go routine destruction](http://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_5).
>   The Go Memory Model also specifically calls out busy waiting without synchronization as an incorrect idiom in this section.

(in your case, there is no guarantee that the value written to `done` in the goroutine will ever be observed by the `main` program)

Here, You need to do some kind of synchronization in the goroutine in order to guarantee that `done=true` happens before one of the iterations of the `for` loop in `main`.

The "`while`" (non-existent in Go) should be replaced by, for instance, a channel you block on (waiting for a communication)

```
for {
    <-c // 2
}
```

Based on a channel (`c := make(chan bool)`) created in `main`, and closed (`close(c)`) in the goroutine.

---

The [sync package](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/) provides other means to wait for a gorountine to end before exiting main.

See for instance Golang Example [Wait until all the background goroutine finish](http://golang-examples.tumblr.com/post/43926847429/wait-until-all-the-background-goroutine-finish):

```
var w sync.WaitGroup
w.Add(1)
go func() {
    // do something
    w.Done()
}
w.Wait()
```