# Golang concurrent download deadlock

Tags: concurrency, go

I want to download files in parallel in go, but my code never exits:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
)

func download_file(file_path string, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    resp, _ := http.Get(file_path)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    filename := filepath.Base(file_path)
    file, _ := os.Create(filename)
    defer file.Close()

    size, _ := io.Copy(file, resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(filename, size, resp.Status)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    file_list := []string{
        "http://i.imgur.com/dxGb2uZ.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/RSU6NxX.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/hUWgS2S.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/U8kaix0.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/w3cEYpY.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/ooSCD9T.jpg"}
    fmt.Println(len(file_list))
    for _, url := range file_list {
        wg.Add(1)
        fmt.Println(wg)
        go download_file(url, wg)

    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

What's the reason? I've looked here: [Golang download multiple files in parallel using goroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635070/golang-download-multiple-files-in-parallel-using-goroutines) but I found no solution.
What is the best way to debug such code?

Comment: You're making a copy of your `WaitGroup`; you should be passing `download_file` a pointer to it.

Comment: Go has some syntactic sugar to call methods with pointer receivers on non-pointer values but you should really think about what you are passing around and a method call always makes a copy.

Comment: Also, you are ignoring errors. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim Cooper said you need to pass the `WaitGroup` as a pointer. If you run the `go vet` tool on your code it will give you this warning:

```
$ go vet ex.go
ex.go:12: download_file passes Lock by value: sync.WaitGroup contains sync.Mutex
exit status 1
```

I recommend using an editor that can do this for you when you save a file. For example [go-plus](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus) for Atom.

As for the code I think you should restructure it like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
)

func downloadFile(filePath string) error {
    resp, err := http.Get(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    name := filepath.Base(filePath)

    file, err := os.Create(name)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    size, err := io.Copy(file, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(name, size, resp.Status)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    fileList := []string{
        "http://i.imgur.com/dxGb2uZ.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/RSU6NxX.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/hUWgS2S.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/U8kaix0.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/w3cEYpY.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/ooSCD9T.jpg"}
    fmt.Println("downloading", len(fileList), "files")
    for _, url := range fileList {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(url string) {
            err := downloadFile(url)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("[error]", url, err)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(url)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I don't like passing `WaitGroup`s around and prefer to keep functions simple, blocking and sequential and then stitch together the concurrency at a higher level. This gives you the option of doing it all sequentially without having to change `downloadFile`.

I also added error handling and fixed names so they are camelCase.

Comment: Is there a convention to use camelCase?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Calab's response, there's absolutely nothing wrong with your approach, all you had to do is to pass a pointer to the `sync.WaitGroup`.

```
func download_file(file_path string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ......
}
.....
        go download_file(url, &wg)
.....
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/4MukvuHm5k)